# How to read a file with mixed binary and ASCII data using C++

Tags: c++, ascii, tokenize, binary-data

I need to read a file with mixed binary and ASCII data using C++ and pure std(no Boost). This data usually contains a mix of nested binary and ASCII headers, followed by binary data and comma separated data. The data is not well aligned, and the binary headers define the number of bytes of the ASCII data, which could be variable from header to header. A section of the data would look like this:

```
[binary header][binary data]The,ASCII,data,[binary header][binary data]is,not,continuous,...
```

I found good tutorials using **read** for binary data and **getline** for ASCII data, and I know that I could read byte by byte using chars, but I was wondering if any of you had to deal with this situation before, and had any useful suggestions on the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: There's probably an easier way, but I would just parse it character by character. Accumulate strings in a buffer and then feed to a stringstream to extract numbers.

Comment: Not enough info.  Is the data record oriented and specified clearly enough that you can define structs?  If not, you'll probably need to read it as binary and then extract the text data.  And by "binary" you do mean binary and not merely numeric, right?

Comment: @Carey I edited the question. I was thinking in extracting the ASCII data as you mentioned, and building the packets recursively.

Comment: From your edited info I'd say you have a multi-step process: 1) Read binary header into a struct, 2) Read binary data into a struct, 3) parse ASCII data. The question is, how do you know the length of the text data?  How do you know where it ends and the next header begins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse a file, you need to know beforehand how it is constructed.

While one file can be a table with the columns separated by commas and rows separated by new lines, another file might be an XML or fully binary with specific field definitions.

If you have a mixture of binary and ASCII data, you must read it all as a binary file.

ASCII characters are no more than binary numbers that represent readable characters.

So you need to know in advance how the file is built and what is the meaning of each byte in the file.

One common way to read such a file is creating a structure with the fields in the file and just reading the file into it.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mystruct_st
{
     int var1;
     char var2;
     char text[10];
}mystruct_t;

mystruct_t mystruct;

int main () {
    FILE * pFile;

    pFile = fopen ( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    fread (&mystruct,sizeof(mystruct_t),1,pFile);

    fclose (pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will only work in exceptional cases, where the format of the binary data corresponds exactly to the internal format.

Comment: Of course, that's why I pointed out that when dealing with a binary file, you need to know how it is structured so you can create a structure that corresponds to the file format. This is the case of an audio wav file for example, and there too you have a mixture of binary and ASCII data on the header

Comment: You answered this in C, this is a C++ question, your answer is not C++ code, but rather C code that you happen to be able to compile in C++.  This is a rather poor answer for that reason alone.

Answer (score 1):

The only real problem is knowing where you change between the
formats in the file.  You'll have to open the file in binary
mode (but that's usually the case for portable files
anyway).  Beyond that, you have to recognize when to switch
between the binary format (which you'll have to implement,
because there isn't one in the standard) and the text format.